# Is there an avr-size equivalent for PICs?

Tags: embedded, pic

I would like to output the amount of flash used when I 'make' my C project written for a PIC, much like Arduino does for its sketches.

[image: Arduino binary sketch size]

I found that the Arduino IDE uses [avr-size](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/man/man1/avr-size.1.html) in on [GitHub](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/6bae5a5dd45adbb31a7195bcb2b85568949acd5e/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt#L36). Is there an equivalent for PICs? I noticed that there's a generic (is that the right word?) version included in GNU's binutils called `size`. Can I use [that](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/binutils_7.html)?

I'm building my project using [sdcc](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/) and [gputils](http://gputils.sourceforge.net/).

**EDIT:** If I pass `-m` to [gplink](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gplink) while linking, I'll get a map file. There's a section in this map file called "Program Memory Usage". At the end of this section, there's the number of addresses used.

```
Program Memory Usage
    Start         End
---------   ---------
0x005558    0x0055db
0x0063e0    0x0063f5
0x00663c    0x006643
...
0x006280    0x0062a7
0x00662e    0x00663b
26229 program addresses used
```

This matches the output of GNU's size when run on the output hex file.

```
$ size out.hex
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      0   26229       0   26229    6675 out.hex
$
```

Does that mean I can just use GNU size? This doesn't seem to match the what I see in my programmer's software. For this same file, the highest address used seems to be 0x6670, which would be the 26,224th byte.

Comment: Program size and flash size are not the same thing. Your .map file will keep program memory, .rodata segements etc listed separately. While some flash programmer tool will only see flash that should be programmed, without having a clue about what the contents do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more detailed summary is provided by `size --format=berkeley a.hex`.  The Berkeley format shows the size of each section in the compiled Intel .hex file and give a grand total at the end.

This is not the same as the highest address used since the different sections go into different areas of memory.

Compiling into ELF format will also give information about RAM usage (text+bss), but not all compilers support that option.